# How do I call a batch file to set environment variables before debugging in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I have shell scripts that set environment vars before running Java applications.  I would like to call these scripts in IntelliJ before running/debugging in the IDE.  I see that I can configure them to run as external tools under Configurations->Before Launch.  However they appear run in another window and the environment vars are not carried over to the session starting the JVM.  Any way to accomplish this?  Thanks.